# Javascript/Ajax : include php on a div with JS/Ajax, without loose previous includes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a navigation bar with elements

```
<ul><li>
```

the element

```
<li>
```

elements pointing with ajax to a separate php function file

```
switch ($_GET['menu']){}
```

with a separate function file accorded to a case (choice). actually functions are separate on a php file which is not included in my site tree. and I lose my includes when I call it. (func_nav.php)

I would like to my function file to be writted in the same file (php file containing HTML and ajax script) or previously included ?

here is the html and ajax (navbar.php)

```
<div id="header_menu_content_align">
<div id="header_menu_content_wrapper">
<div id="menu">


<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="uniqueId01">Home</li>
  <li id="uniqueId02">User
    <ul>
      <li id="uniqueId03">Sous-item 1</li>
      <li id="uniqueId04">Sous-item 2</li>
      <li id="uniqueId05">Sous-item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="uniqueId06">Admin</li>
</ul>


</div>
</div>  
</div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(){
$.get('function/navigation/func_nav.php', { menu: this.id }, function(data){
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html(data); // inject HTML into above DIV,
});
});

</script>
```

here is the php file i want to include or call with all my previous includes

```
<?php



switch($_GET['menu']){

    case 'uniqueId01':
        menu1();
        break;
    case 'uniqueId02':
        menu2();
        break;
    case 'uniqueId03':
        menu3();
        break;
    case 'uniqueId04':
        menu4();
        break;
    case 'uniqueId05':
        menu5();
        break;
    case 'uniqueId06':
        menu6();
        break;
    default:
        someDefaultFunction();
        break;
}

function menu1(){
    include '/desktop/content/corporate01/content.php';
}
function menu2(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu USER! ';
}
function menu3(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 3! ';
}
function menu4(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 4! ';
}
function menu5(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 5! ';
}
function menu6(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 6! ';
}


?>
```

I would like to keep my includes => include => include => include html => include html i have some includes like SSO.php controller (desktop mobile) etc.

I would like my "get" not pointing to a file but to a included function..

```
$.get('function/navigation/func_nav.php', { menu: this.id }, function(data){
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html(data); // inject HTML into above DIV,
});
```

A friend working with me developped this to solve the problem, iam actually trying with this

```
<div id="header_menu_content_align">
<div id="header_menu_content_wrapper">
<div id="menu">


<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="uniqueId01">Home</li>
  <li id="uniqueId02">User
    <ul>
      <li id="uniqueId03">Sub-item 1</li>
      <li id="uniqueId04">Sub-item 2</li>
      <li id="uniqueId05">Sub-item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="uniqueId06">Admin</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>  
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){

    var menu_id = event.currentTarget.id;
    getMenu(menu_id);
});

function getMenu(menu_id) {

    switch(menu_id) {
        case 'uniqueId01':
            menu1();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId02':
            menu2();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId03':
            menu3();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId04':
            menu4();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId05':
            menu5();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId06':
            menu6();
            break;
        default:
            console.log("default case");
            break;
    }
}

function menu1() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu2() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/home/home.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu3() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php echo app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/toto.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu4() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu5() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu6() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>' );
}

</script>
```

but actually function not work with submenu elements..

i have tryed with class property to li but don't work, parent element is displayed in place of subelement..

```
<div id="header_menu_content_align">
<div id="header_menu_content_wrapper">
<div id="menu">


<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="uniqueId01" class="toto">Home</li>
  <li id="uniqueId02" class="toto">User
    <ul>
      <li id="uniqueId03" class="toto">Sub item 1</li>
      <li id="uniqueId04" class="toto">Sub item 2</li>
      <li id="uniqueId05" class="toto">Sub item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="uniqueId06" class="toto">Admin</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>  
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.toto').on('click', function(event){

    var menu_id = event.currentTarget.id;
    getMenu(menu_id);
});

function getMenu(menu_id) {

    switch(menu_id) {
        case 'uniqueId01':
            menu1();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId02':
            menu2();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId03':
            menu3();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId04':
            menu4();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId05':
            menu5();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId06':
            menu6();
            break;
        default:
            console.log("default case");
            break;
    }
}

function menu1() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu2() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/home/home.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu3() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php echo app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/totosub1.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu4() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php echo app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/totosub2.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu5() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php echo app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/totosub3.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu6() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php echo app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/totoadmin.php'; ?>' );
}

</script>
```

i have also tryed with this (iam not far from the good result)

```
<?php

if ($_GET['menu']!= '') {


    switch($_GET['menu']){

        case 'uniqueId01':
            menu1();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId02':
            menu2();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId03':
            menu3();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId04':
            menu4();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId05':
            menu5();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId06':
            menu6();
            break;
        default:
            someDefaultFunction();
            break;
    }
}


function menu1(){
    include '/var/www/html/myeternal/app/template/desktop/content/corporate01/content.php';
}
function menu2(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu USER! ';
}
function menu3(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 3! ';
}
function menu4(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 4! ';
}
function menu5(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 5! ';
}
function menu6(){
    echo 'You clicked Menu 6! ';
}


?>



<div id="header_menu_content_align">
<div id="header_menu_content_wrapper">
<div id="menu">


<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="uniqueId01">Home</li>
  <li id="uniqueId02">User
    <ul>
      <li id="uniqueId03">Sous-item 1</li>
      <li id="uniqueId04">Sous-item 2</li>
      <li id="uniqueId05">Sous-item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="uniqueId06">Admin</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>  
</div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(){

$.get(' ', { menu: this.id }, function(data){

    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html(data); // inject HTML into above DIV,
});

});

</script>

<div id="wrapper_page_desktop_content"> </div>
```

but with this, container for this html/php is displayed in the wrapper_page_desktop_content

Comment: Why do you want them in the same file? I would suggest you include without the functions so instead of menu1() , use include('...')

Comment: I would like my functions to be "include" not necessarily on the same file but in the tree of my site, in order not to lose my "includes" prerequisites, I do not wish at this stage to use session variables if possible ! a friend tell me to write javascript functions in the same file to not loose my previous includes, please help :)  (iam very new in javascript ;) )

Answer (score 0):

a friend has developped this to solve the problem

```
<div id="header_menu_content_align">
<div id="header_menu_content_wrapper">
<div id="menu">


<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="uniqueId01" class="displayPage">Home</li>
  <li id="uniqueId02">User
    <ul style="display:none">
      <li id="uniqueId03" class="displayPage">Sub-item 1</li>
      <li id="uniqueId04" class="displayPage">Sub-item 2</li>
      <li id="uniqueId05" class="displayPage">Sub-item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="uniqueId06" class="displayPage">Admin</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>  
</div>


<div id="wrapper_page_desktop_content"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
    var menu_id = event.currentTarget.id;
    if($(this).hasClass('displayPage')) {

        getMenu(menu_id);
        event.stopPropagation(); //Stop les event JS qui suivent
    } else {
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
        getMenu(menu_id);
    }

});

function getMenu(menu_id) {
    console.log(menu_id);
    switch(menu_id) {
        case 'uniqueId01':
            menu1();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId02':
            menu2();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId03':
            menu3();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId04':
            menu4();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId05':
            menu5();
            break;
        case 'uniqueId06':
            menu6();
            break;
        default:
            console.log("default case");
            break;
    }
}

function menu1() {
    console.log('menu 1 ');
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<p>ok 1</p>' );
}

function menu2() {
    console.log('menu 2 ');
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<p>ok 2</p>' );
}

function menu3() {
    console.log('menu 3 ');
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<p>ok 3</p>' );
}

function menu4() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu5() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>' );
}

function menu6() {
    $('#wrapper_page_desktop_content').html( '<?php include app_dir . 'template/desktop/content/corporate01/test.php'; ?>' );
}

</script>
```